# Query to convert a unknown value to json

Tags: postgresql

I have the structure like,

```
select to_json('[{
   "11111":
       {
        "Number":{"11111"},
        "createdTime":"2018-06-25 10:30:11.047 +0530",
        "errorMessage":"invalid" 
       }                                            
    }]')
```

If I try to convert to json structure, I am getting the following error:

> ERROR: could not determine polymorphic type because input has type unknown

I need to get a valid json format.

Thanks..

Comment: Might avoid future mishaps: There are online json-validator such as [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) that will tell you if it's valid json or not - or you could read through the different [drafts](http://json-schema.org/specification.html) and their definitions..

Comment: I have done with json validator tool also.I came to knew that the structure is not avalid json . I need to write a query to remove brackets {'1111'}

Answer (score 0):

`to_json` is used to convert e.g. a record or other values that are not a JSON value to proper a JSON value.

You apparently want  to use a string value as a JSON.

In order to be able to do that, you need to supply valid JSON. The part `"Number":{"11111"}`  is however invalid JSON, you need to remove the curly braces.

```
select '[{
   "11111":
       {
        "Number": "11111",
        "createdTime":"2018-06-25 10:30:11.047 +0530",
        "errorMessage":"invalid" 
       }                                            
    }]'::json
```

But why are you using a JSON array if you only have a single value? From what you have shown a single JSON value would make more sense:

```
select '{
   "11111":
       {
        "Number": "11111",
        "createdTime":"2018-06-25 10:30:11.047 +0530",
        "errorMessage":"invalid" 
       }                                            
    }'::json
```